# Views Pager with ajax not working on any theme

Tags: views, ajax, paging

Views pager with Ajax loading is not working on any theme.. I tried Bartik, Seven, garland Themes .. also tried to disable all modules but still not working.

I also tried enable/disable ajax in my view, Update Views modules and Drupal to latest versions.

Views still has ajax overlay when adding fields or filter criteria  .. the problem is only in pager.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you open the console (F12 in most browsers) and check if you see errors?

Comment: As I tried all themes (admin theme like Seven) or default drupal themes Like Bartik, I looked to console and found NO errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough information to help you. What you describe is pretty basic and should just work. Have you tried different browsers? Does the pager work if you disable ajax in the view?

Comment: no if i disables the ajax or enabled it... nothing happen. what made me out of mind is that ajax works fine when adding fields or filter criteria in views.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots?

Comment: are you using a Global php field on your view? If yes, then it's not your ajax. This is known problem with the latest version of views (7.38) here is patch for it https://www.drupal.org/node/2401677.